# How do i compare 2 strings in shell?

Tags: shell, if-statement, sh

I want the user to input something at the command line either -l or -e.
so e.g. $./report.sh -e
I want an if statement to split up whatever decision they make so i have tried...

```
if [$1=="-e"]; echo "-e"; else; echo "-l"; fi
```

obviously doesn't work though
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I use:

```
if [[ "$1" == "-e" ]]; then
    echo "-e"
else
    echo "-l";
fi
```

However, for parsing arguments, `getopts` might make your life easier:

```
while getopts "el" OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         e)
             echo "-e"
             ;;
         l)
             echo "-l"
             ;;
     esac
done
```

Comment: You say "getopt" and "getopts". They're two different things. The former is a separate executable and the latter is a shell builtin.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it all on one line (usually it makes it hard to read):

```
if [ "$1" = "-e" ]; then echo "-e"; else echo "-l"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces between the square brackets and what goes inside them.  Also, just use a single `=`.  You also need a `then`.

```
if [ $1 = "-e" ]
then
   echo "-e"
else
   echo "-l"
fi
```

The problem specific to `-e` however is that it has a special meaning in `echo`, so you are unlikely to get anything back.  If you try `echo -e` you'll see nothing print out, while `echo -d` and `echo -f` do what you would expect.  Put a space next to it, or enclose it in brackets, or have some other way of making it not exactly `-e` when sending to `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print which parameter the user has submitted, you can simply use `echo "$1"`. If you want to fall back to a default value if the user hasn't submitted anything, you can use `echo "${1:--l}` (`:-` is the Bash syntax for default values). However, if you want really powerful and flexible argument handling, you could look into `getopt`:

```
params=$(getopt --options f:v --longoptions foo:,verbose --name "my_script.sh" -- "$@")

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "getopt failed"
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$params"

while true
do
    case $1 in
        -f|--foo)
            foobar="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -v|--verbose)
            verbose='--verbose'
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            while [ -n "$3" ]
            do
                targets[${#targets[*]}]="$2"
                shift
            done
            source_dir=$(readlink -fn -- "$2")
            shift 2
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unhandled parameter $1"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ $# -ne 0 ]
then
    error "Extraneous parameters." "$help_info" $EX_USAGE
fi
```